# Using Hbase Thrift2 API in C++

Tags: c++, hbase, thrift

I've been using the Thrift API for HBase in C++ (example usage [here](http://www.alexbod.com/c-plus-plus-hbase-client/)), but now I have a need to use Thrift2 instead. I know there are examples for using Thrift2 in other languages, such as C#, Python, and Java, but I can't find documentation for C++.

Here's my current code for calling the Thrift API:

```
transport->open();
std::string t("demo_table");

/ Scan all tables, look for the demo table and delete it. /
std::cout << "scanning tables..." << std::endl;
StrVec tables;
client.getTableNames(tables);
for (StrVec::const_iterator it = tables.begin(); it != tables.end(); ++it) {
    std::cout << " found: " << *it << std::endl;
    if (t == *it) {
        if (client.isTableEnabled(*it)) {
            std::cout << " disabling table: " << *it << std::endl;
            client.disableTable(*it);
        }
        std::cout << " deleting table: " << *it << std::endl;
        client.deleteTable(*it);
    }
}
```

Now this fails after switching to Thrift2. For example, client.getTableNames() no longer works (the function doesn't exist).

Comment: How doesn't it work. Still no MCVE issue for closure

Comment: The function doesn't exist. There's no documentation for how to do the same functionality with Thrift2 as I was for Thrift.

Comment: Fair enough. Question reopened

Answer (score 0):

Some functions are removed from hbase thrift2 interface. If you just want to get list of table names in hbase, you can use get children of /hbase/table in zookeeper.

```
struct String_vector paths;
int ret = zoo_get_children(zkhandle,"/hbase/table", 0,&paths);//
if(ret)
{
    std::cout << "zoo_get_children error " << ret << std::endl;       
} else {
    for(i = 0;i < paths.count;i++)
        printf("/hbase/table/%s\n",paths.data[i]);  
    free_vector(&paths);  
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but we've actually gone a different direction now. Using a Java client instead of Thrift.